# How to create links or Ids to sections or CTAs on the same page in handlebars.java?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, hyperlink, handlebars.java

I have come here with a concern. We want a structure of linking for different CTAs on same page of our client's website. Like, if someone opens the link https://www.smansha.com/webinar/#book-a-private-demo/ then it should open with respective pop-up directly.

Same for this: https://www.smansha.com/webinar/#attend-a-free-webinar/ Your suggestion would be appreciated much if you could help me how to make this structure possible.

Thanks in advance.

Jitender

Comment: this should be elementary.. You do have your `(click)="myClickFunction($event)"` on those various buttons/anchors? so you can pass the popup link as the second prop ( `myClickFunction($event, 'targetlink.dev')` ) and just use it in the handler `myClickFunction( e: Event, link: String) => window.open(link)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
Are you talking about event tracking creation?

Comment: Not really. Event handling. https://angular.io/guide/user-input